# Phone number change across website

Tags: php, html, css

What would be the best way to have a phone number change across a site universally?

For example, if I have 3 pages with the phone number on it, and want to change that number but don't want to do it 3 different times, how can I create a variable that will allow me to just put that in those pages and just change it in one place?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to create a constant in a config file that is included in all your pages.  Then reference that constant on any page that requires the phone number.

```
define('PHONE', '123-456-7890');
```

This method has the benefit of being able to ignore scope.  Global variables still need to be declared inside of functions.

To render the phone number in PHP you would just do this:

```
echo PHONE;
```

Comment: is that "const" only able to be put into PhP?  Or can I shove that in a CSS Style  Sheet as well?

Comment: It's only PHP.  CSS is style, not content.  It is also on the client side (think html/css/javascript) not the server side (php).

Comment: pardon, im very new to coding, but do I basically just make an info.php type thing, and then reference that info.php in lets say footer.php, and then in footer.php I also need to have the echo PHONE?  How do I reference a config file in PhP?  Thank you

Comment: A: outside of classes, you have to use: define('SOMECONST', 45); const is an in class syntax only.  B: You could actually set up a css file to use php if you serve that extension via .htaccess or apache config.

Comment: I think this stuff is a little over my head. If I have a header.php and a footer.php as well as other php pages. I want the number to match in both footer.php and the scattered pages. Where should I assign the variable and then for that matter how do I call it?

Comment: Either define the constant in header.php itself or in a file that you `include` at the top of header.php that way anywhere below that point in a page (including inside of footer.php) you can use the `PHONE` constant.

Answer (score -3):

At its simplest...

`phone_number.txt`:

```
555-555-5555
```

Your other files:

```
<html>
  ... stuff
  <?php include('phone_number.txt'); ?>
  ... stuff
</html>
```

Anything more complicated would need some more info on your setup.

Comment: Even simpler, just have the `phone_number.txt` file be `555-555-5555` without any PHP, and `include` that. It'll print the number right there.

Comment: This is really bad.  Never have php that does not have a php file extension.  This one case may be innocuous but it teaches very bad habits.  If you accidentally store a password or some other private information, anybody could just download the text file.  If it's a php file then malicious users will only get the output of the php file which is nothing.

Comment: Also, this example doesn't work.  You would still need to render the included variable inside the php block.

Comment: Brainfart. Fixed. @evan I think this'd be hard to accidentally include sensitive variables in, but adjusted. Ultimately, he needs some sort of templating system with shared header/footer that makes all of this a non-issue.

Comment: @evan I have a header.php and a footer.php..  I also have other php pages.  I want the number to match in both footer.php and the scattered pages.  Where should I assign the variable and then for that matter how do I call it?  Thanks again

Comment: Do you have a configuration include file as well as `header.php`? You could pop a `<?php $phone_number = '555-555-5555'; ?>` at the top of `header.php` and use <?php echo $phone_number; ?>` wherever you want it, but a config file would be a much nicer spot.

Comment: Ok so basically just create an info.php and then call the info from that?